# Изменение размеров UIImageView созданного в Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode7

Добрый день. Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

есть `UIImageView` созданный в сториборде. В приложении я хочу изменить его размеры, в зависимости от ширины экрана устройства. Делаю это следующим образом:

```
UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1158-1449142390.jpg"];
_imageView.image = img;
NSLog(@" Размер _imageView Шаг1: %f x %f",_imageView.frame.size.width,_imageView.frame.size.height);
    CGSize scrSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    CGSize imgSize = img.size;
    CGFloat leftMargin = 8.0f;
    CGFloat viewWidth = (scrSize.width - (leftMargin * 2));
    CGFloat viewHeight  = imgSize.height * viewWidth / imgSize.width;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(leftMargin, 20, viewWidth, viewHeight);
[_imageView setFrame:frame];
_imageView.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
_imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
//    _imageView.image = img;
[self.view addSubview:_imageView];
NSLog(@" Размер _imageView Шаг2: %f x %f",_imageView.frame.size.width,_imageView.frame.size.height);
```

При запуске ничего не изменяется. но в `NSLog` выводятся Шаг1 и Шаг2 выводятся разные размеры. Кто подскажет, какой момент я упускаю?

Кстати, если создаю `UIImageView` из кода, то всё нормально меняется. Заранее благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Потратил много времени, ничего не найдя. Стоило только задать вопрос, ответ случайно выплыл, там где этого не искал. Нужно просто отключить AutoLayout и SizeClass